# Convert.ToDouble throws error in French System

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing a problem when string converting a string value to double value. 
Eg:

```
string val="2.0";
double dval=Convert.ToDouble(val);
```

On executing this code on a French system threw an error because in french they use ,(comma) instead of .(dot).

Any solution???

Comment: Do you need parsing to succeed OR you need `val` to have comma?

Comment: The reason it throws an error is because it's expecting the string to be in the current culture. This works as expected if the string comes from user input (e.g. a French person would type 2,0). If the string comes from somewhere else (e.g. a database) you will know what culture the string is. So it kinda depends how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Convert.ToDouble(val, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
Double.Parse(val, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use correct Culture to parse data.

If "2.0" comes from some standard source (i.e. XML) use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (as abatishcev suggested).

If "2.0" comes from user input from known culture - use that culture (sample for en-US):

```
double dval = Double.Parse("2.0", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

If it was from input from local user it should be in correct user's Culture settings - should be "2,0" for "fr-FR".

If you don't know what culuture was used to enter the "2.0" value it is better to simply stop and think what culture should be used.

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should be cheaper and has the separator as a dot by spec but still a good and valid point.